# What is TIDX File Format?

Tags: file-format

I just got a file from my client that has `.tidx` extension. He want to convert that file into PDF. I don't know which file format is this & how read it. If anyone can help me with this.

Comment: Hi Khurram Ilyas, welcome to [softwarerecs.se]! This question does not appear to be about software recommendations, within [the scope defined on meta](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope) and in the [help center](/help/on-topic). If you think you can [edit] it to become on-topic, please have a look at the [question quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/23377).

Answer (score 0):

> TIDX file is an AACS Thumbnail Index File. Advanced Access Content System (AACS) is a specification for managing content stored on the next generation of prerecorded and recorded optical media for consumer use with PCs and CE devices. menu.tidx and mark.tidx has the index information for the thumbnail. menu.tidx includes the index information to the pictures used for the menu presentation.

*[source](https://www.filesuffix.com/en/extension/tidx)*

I'm not familiar with this particular filetype, but it sounds like your client have sent you the wrong file.